Under what circumstances is this Rust code safe?
I am currently looking at making the following code a bit less "problematic":
#[allow(clippy::mut_from_ref)]
#[allow(invalid_reference_casting)]
unsafe fn unsafe_ref_mut(&self) -> &mut Self {
    // Use read_volatile to prevent compiler to optimize assignment to the returned reference away
    let const_ptr = std::ptr::read_volatile(&self) as *const Self;
    let mut_ptr = const_ptr as *mut Self;
    &mut *mut_ptr
}

pub(crate) unsafe fn set_kind(&self, kind: Kind) {
    unsafe {
        self.unsafe_ref_mut().kind = kind;
    }
}

I did not write this code myself, but I did add the attributes to silence the compiler warnings. Turns out that the rust compiler really doesn't want you to cast an immutable borrow to a mutable one and there's also undefined behaviour involved somewhere. It seems to work, but I'd rather prefer to use a safer method.
What I came up with is the following:
fn as_mut_ptr(&self) -> *mut Self {
    (self as *const Self).cast_mut()
}

pub(crate) unsafe fn set_kind(&self, kind: Kind) {
    (*self.as_mut_ptr()).kind = kind;
}

First of all, I'm somewhat surprised that casting an immutable reference to a mutable pointer is perfectly safe in rust. The only thing unsafe seems to be dereferencing that pointer.
Therefore, my question is: Under what circumstances is this code safe, i.e., what would I need to write into a Safety section in the documentation of the set_kind function?
From my understanding:

The pointer needs to be non-null and well aligned (I assume this I can always guarantee since only Rust code ever creates the struct that these methods reside in)
No two threads may access the function at the same time
The struct cannot be shared.

Are these all requirements? Am I missing something?

Simply put, there are no circumstances in which trying to turn a &self into a &mut self is memory safe. Please do not try to do it. Prefer other mechanisms such as memory synchronization constructs (Mutex) or redesigning the code to prevent such transformations. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/transmutes.html

Is the same also true for pointers? I.e., I'm not turning &self into &mut self, but rather into *mut Self. Is the problem still the same?

@Schottky Just casting raw pointers (ie. *const T to *mut T) in itself is not dangerous, but when you dereference them you must be sure that you can do it. Which in particular means, that during dereferencing there does not exist &T anywhere which points to the same memory. The only "escape hatch" is UnsafeCell, but it still does not turn of mutability xor aliasing rules that all Rust code must abide by. When in doubt, better just use standard mechanisms to synchronize data (like for example Mutex).
